# How do I upload multiple images using multer in node js?

Tags: javascript, node.js

I am making API for multiple image uploading in node js.
So can you please help me out, how to upload only images and not another file

```
var Express = require('express');
var multer = require('multer');
var bodyParser = require('body-parser');
var app = Express();
app.use(bodyParser.json());
var Storage = multer.diskStorage({
    destination: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, "./Images");
    },
    filename: function (req, file, callback) {
        callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
    }
});

var upload = multer({ storage: Storage }).array("imgUploader", 3); //Field name and max count

app.get("/", function (req, res) {
    res.sendFile(__dirname + "/index.html");
});

app.post("/api/Upload", function (req, res) {
    upload(req, res, function (err) {

        if (err) {
            return res.end("Something went wrong!");
        }
        return res.end("File uploaded sucessfully!.");
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can add a `fileFilter` function to your `multer` options. So with a bit of refactoring:

```
var options = {
  storage: multer.diskStorage({
      destination: function (req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, "./Images");
      },
      filename: function (req, file, callback) {
          callback(null, file.fieldname + "_" + Date.now() + "_" + file.originalname);
      }
  }),
  fileFilter: function (req, file, callback) {
    const isPhoto = file.mimetype.indexOf("image/") === 0
    if (isPhoto) {
      callback(null, true) // true if valid
    } else {
      callback({ message: 'An optional error message'}, false) // false if invalid
    }
  }
}
```

And then use these options:

```
var upload = multer(options).array("imgUploader", 3);
```

See: https://github.com/expressjs/multer#filefilter

`accept="image/*"` on your input will only provide client side validation, and can be removed with the dev console.

Answer (score 0):

Use `accept` attribute for your input.

```html
<input type="file" name="pic" accept="image/*">
```